# Static webpage on Nginx Docker Container Missing CSS

Tags: css, nginx, docker, swagger

I am trying to host the Swagger UI on a docker container using Nginx.

When I access my webpage via [hostAddress.com](http://hostAddress.com/swagger) it returns the webpage as plain text and inspecting it tells me that it can't find any of the javascript or css files despite them seeming to be present in the container as I have ssh into the container to check.

My dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY src /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.config

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;


  location /swagger {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}

#Static File Caching. All static files with the following extension will be cached for 1 day
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
  expires 1d;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please see if this helps, may be an alternative though - https://github.com/ianneub/docker-swagger-ui

Comment: had a look at that, however due to other things running on the same server I need to be able to assign the location of /swagger which I don't think is possible with that.

Comment: Do you mean custom context path to the url? You may look his `Dockerfile` which is available there and do your own, works?

Comment: So to access my swagger page it has to be accessed via http://serverURL.com/swagger, from what i've read this is achieved via the nginx.conf file so not really sure how that could be done from the dockerfile.

Comment: You may look the answer and see if that is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you can do achieve that.

Like it was mentioned the comment, you can download the artifacts from 
https://github.com/ianneub/docker-swagger-ui/blob/master

- Create a directory say ngix
- Copy [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ianneub/docker-swagger-ui/blob/master/Dockerfile), [run.sh](https://github.com/ianneub/docker-swagger-ui/blob/master/run.sh) into that directory
- Edit the `Dockerfile` to make the customization that you need to change the location as shown below:

```
FROM nginx:1.9

ENV SWAGGER_UI_VERSION 2.1.2-M2
ENV URL **None**

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -L https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/v${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar -zxv -C /tmp \
    && mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/swagger \
    && cp -R /tmp/swagger-ui-${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/swagger \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

COPY run.sh /run.sh

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

- If you compare the above changes with original `Dockerfile`, there are changes made in the lines 9, 10 to include additional path i.e., `swagger`. Of course, you may change as needed.

Next, run the following docker commands to build and run

**Build Image:**

```
docker build -t myswagger .
```

**Run it**

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3000:80 --name testmyswagger -e "URL=http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json" myswagger
```

Now you should be able to access your swagger using http://localhost:3000/swagger/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help got it working, followed this and got it working. Then went back to my original attempt and added a swagger folder and used the config to append index.html onto the end of the url and it returns it perfectly.

Comment: @user3473406, glad to know that this answer is helpful.