# Django and nginx with docker compose - static files are not loaded

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I know that several similar questions have been asked, but I have not managed to find a proper answer anywhere.

I want to dockerize my Django app. The app works fine in the docker container but the static files (images, css etc.) are not loaded.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2' 
services:   
  web:
    build: .
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/www/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - web
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - web
```

The `start.sh` script

```
python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

exec gunicorn audiobridge.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `web` container:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
```

Then I have an nginx/ directory in my project which has the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx
COPY sites-enabled/audiobridge /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and inside nginx/sites-enabled there is the nginx configuration file:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name 127.0.0.1;
charset utf-8;

location /static {
    alias /app/www/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the same image. But related to css files, please check this to see if that is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280648/static-webpage-on-nginx-docker-container-missing-css/40282302#40282302

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing slash to location so that it's `location /static/`?

Comment: Post your `docker-compose logs`

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEzM.png)

```
volumes:
  - "../nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/templates"
  - "/static:/static"
```

Did you try add this code to nginx and django app?